# Adding key-value pair to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having some trouble adding a key-value pair to a nested dictionary. The new pair seems to be getting added to ALL entries in the outer dictionary, instead of just the nested dictionary that I want.

Here's an example:

```
mykeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
mydictionary = dict.fromkeys(mykeys, {})
mydictionary['key1']['subkey1'] = 'value1'
mydictionary
```

I'm expecting to see the following, with 'subkey1' only being added to the 'key1' dictionary:

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 'value1'},
 'key2': {},
 'key3': {}}
```

Instead, it adds the subkey1/value1 pair to every element of the outer dictionary:

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 'value1'},
 'key2': {'subkey1': 'value1'},
 'key3': {'subkey1': 'value1'}}
```

Why is this the case, and how can I re-write my code to fix this mistake?

Comment: You provide the same object as subdictionary as value of all main dict keys.

Comment: Instead of `fromkeys`, you can try `mydictionary = {k:{} for k in mykeys}
`

Answer (score 4):

`mydictionary['key1'] = {'subkey1': 'value1'}`

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: perfect , Thank you

Comment: by me it overwrites every time the dictionary:(